# Determine if a Hash function is pre-image resistant and collision free

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, preimage-resistance

I'm so confused by this kind of exercise.

We have that $n = p * q$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers. Let's examine this hash function:
$h(x) = x^2 \mod n$.

Determine if the hash function is pre-image resistant.
Can you have collisions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is confusing? Is the tasks not clear or the task is clear but you find it hard to know how to start?..

Comment: the second one, i think i understand the task, but where should i start?

Comment: There are two general ways to answer this problem: 1) find a way to show that, if you can find a preimage/collision, you can solve a specific hard problem (e.g. factoring or computing a discrete log), and 2) here's a way to find a preimage/collision.  BTW: are the factors of $p, q$ public, or is the factorization of $n$ secret?  It turns out that the answer to one of the two depends on that...

Comment: Hint: consider the input set of $h$. If it's $\mathbb Z$, it's trivial to find a collision. If it's $|0,n)$ and $n$ is public, that's still easy. If it's $|0,(n-1)/2]$, well, as poncho says, you need to consider if factoring $n$ is hard.